# How can I mark all references to a highlighted word in the scroll bar?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

What options are there for getting Visual Studio 2015 to mark all references in the scroll bar to a highlighted word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2015) will do this; with the "Match Margin" option enabled, it puts purple dots in the scroll bar for all the matches:

[image: Demonstration of the "Match Margin" feature with map-mode scroll bar]

At first I tried the RockMargin2015 extension since other SO answers (for older IDE versions) recommended older versions of that, but I found that RockMargin substitutes the map-mode scroll bar with its own (inferior) version and changes theme colors. I didn't like how poorly it cooperated with the IDE, so I switched to the above.

Comment: How do I change the color in which the matches are highlighted in the scrollbar?

Comment: @Valentin I recommend asking that as a separate question on Stack Overflow. I'm not sure if there is an option to change the color, and your question will get much more visibility if you [post a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

[Productivity Power Tools](https://www.visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d) shows references in a mapped scroll bar in a fashion similar to the above example.  I don't believe it provides the ability to customize the colors for those references.  Hope this helps.